# gradle build --warning-mode=all warning annotation processors deprecated use processor path instead

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

when I do `gradle clean build --warning-mode=all`, I get the following warning:

```
Putting annotation processors on the compile classpath has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please add them to the processor path instead. If these processors were unintentionally leaked on the compile classpath, use the -proc:none compiler option to ignore them..
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.10.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }

}
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
    compile "org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:1.3.1"
    compile files("libs/ojdbc7.jar")
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
    compile group: "javax.inject", name: "javax.inject", version: "1"
    runtime "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools"
    providedRuntime "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    testCompile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test"
}
bootRepackage {
    enabled = false
}
```

I do not understand what is the warning about. I am fairly new to Gradle. I need help understanding what are the `annotation processors` that I am supposedly using and how to use `processor path` instead.

Answer (score 1):

**What are `annotation processors?`**

> Annotation processors are Java modules/libraries that act as a hook
>   into the compile process of the java compiler, to analyze the source
>   code for user-defined annotations and handle then (by producing
>   compiler errors, compiler warning, emitting source code, bytecode
>   ...).

**How I am supposedly using it?**

> One of your compile dependencies must be bringing the annotation
>   processors behind the scenes.

**How to use processor path instead?**

> As per Gradle [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/release-notes.html#convenient-declaration-of-annotation-processor-dependencies), you can add annotation processor
>   configuration like below

```
dependencies {
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8'
}
```

Alternatively, you can put `-proc:none` in your compiler argument to ignore it as per this [guideline](https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/release-notes.html#putting-annotation-processors-on-the-compile-classpath-or-explicit--processorpath-compiler-argument)